Why is this shape homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of three circles?
The below image depicts two examples, wherein the arrows denote morphisms that are homotopy equivalences.
I’m trying to understand why, in (I), $X_1$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y_1$. My only intuition is that we can “continuously move” the rightmost circle, for ex., such that its point of intersection with the middle circle = point of intersection of leftmost circle with middle circle. But since these are the same points on the middle circle, the points of intersection reduce to a single point (the solid yellow dot in $Y_1$). However, we don’t want to impose any other equivalences, so for example we don’t count the other apparent point of intersections as actual points of intersection. Thus, we really get the shape $Y_1$ via this continuous movement.
Is this the right way to see it? I’m unsure because the above idea is really saying that if we identify the points of intersections in the first space, we preserve homotopy type. But I don’t think quotients usually preserve homotopy type?
One thing I do realize is that it is not sufficient to simply move the circles as we please, while being “lazy” with distinguishing points: if we were lazy and forgot to distinguish points of intersection, we could show a figure 8 is homotopy equivalent to a single circle, which is absurd. This makes me think I’m on the right track above?


If you identify the points, you indeed get a different homotopy type. Instead, you want to look at the "direct" path between these two points in the middle circle and contract it. For how to make this rigorous, see Hatcher, Proposition 0.17. Seeing this and your last question, I'd recommend taking the time to read through the relevant parts of Chapter 0 of Hatcher altogether; it will benefit your understanding.

On another note, while I understand where the idea of "simply moving circles as we please, while being 'lazy' with distinguishing points" and the resulting confusion comes from, it's technically speaking nonsense: You seem to conceptualize these things as living in the plane, but here there is no ambient space for the circles to move through. All movement is confined to the confines of the circles themselves, so to speak.

You don't move; you shrink the part of the middle circle between points of its intersections with the other two circles.

Thank you both! That is definitely an important point. So that shrinkage is essentially deformation retract of a line onto a point?

@algebroo Yes, that would be correct.

@BenSteffan referring to your comment about there being no ambient space here: are we never allowed to do continuous movements in some ambient space to justify homotopy equivalence? For example, isn’t is possible that ‘intermediate shapes resultant of movements in ambient space’ are homeomorphic to subsets of the domain, so that this might be allowed?

@BenSteffan (new comment to make each shorter) For ex., I thought we can “continuously move the right circle until its point of intersection is same as left circle” because the intermediate steps are homeomorphic copies of the initial space.
